# Hive filter values that only belongs to a given List of String or a combination from its elements

Tags: sql, select, hive, hiveql, where-clause

I am working on hive tables and I have to extract data based on geographic locations.
I need to only filter data of the AMER region I mean where the column **contrycode** only contains one or any combination from this list **'ARG', 'BHS', 'BRA', 'CAN', 'CUB', 'MEX', 'USA', 'VEN'**. Is there any hive operator that can filter data based on this specification: **contrycode contains one or a combination from a given list**?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hi create a table where you  can have mapping of continent and country mapping .
do inner join and get the data.

```
ie  Contmaptable

   country_code , continent


 query wiil look like 
     select * 
     from youtable  yt
     join  Contmaptable cm
     on yt.country_code =cm.country_code
     and continent = 'AMAR'
```

Comment: I created a udf function with scala, it was simpler:

class FilterCodePaysAMER extends UDF {
  def evaluate(s1: String, a1: Array[String]): Boolean = {
    s1
      .replaceAll("\\[", "")
      .replaceAll("\\]", "")
      .split(",")
      .map(x => a1.contains(x))
      .reduce((b1, b2) => b1 && b2)

  }

Answer (score 0):

I added a UDF function:

```
class FilterCodePaysAMER extends UDF {
  def evaluate(s1: String, a1: Array[String]): Boolean = {
    s1
      .replaceAll("\\[", "")
      .replaceAll("\\]", "")
      .split(",")
      .map(x => a1.contains(x))
      .reduce((b1, b2) => b1 && b2)

  }
```

so when I call the function:

```
val a1 = Array("ARG", "BHS", "BRA", "CAN", "CUB", "MEX", "USA", "VEN")
filter.evaluate("[CAN,USA,ARG,USA,USA,BRA,CAN,BHS,USA,USA,VEN,CUB,MEX,USA,USA,USA,CAN,USA,TUN]", a1)
```

it returns **false** because TUN does not belong to the input list representing the AMER Region